# Set top level axis for navigation toolbar and pick events

Tags: python, python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

If I have a shared y axis and two x axis, how can I specify which axis I want to use? In my situation I want to have the default axes being displayed in the toolbar and such be the subplot created, and have the second axes generated via `twiny()` not be displayed. Here's a minimal example you can run to see my problem:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('TkAgg')

from numpy import arange, sin, pi
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2TkAgg
from matplotlib.backend_bases import key_press_handler
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
import Tkinter as Tk

root = Tk.Tk()
root.wm_title("Embedding in TK")


f = Figure(figsize=(5,4), dpi=100)
a = f.add_subplot(111)
t = arange(0.0,3.0,0.01)
s = sin(2*pi*t)

a.plot(t,s)

y = a.twiny()

# a tk.DrawingArea
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(f, master=root)
canvas.show()
canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

toolbar = NavigationToolbar2TkAgg( canvas, root )
toolbar.update()
canvas._tkcanvas.pack(side=Tk.TOP, fill=Tk.BOTH, expand=1)

Tk.mainloop()
```

As you can see if you run it: [image]

The coordinate system in the bottom right is using the `twiny()` axes, when I want the program to use the **other** one. How can this be done?

Checking the [docs](http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html#matplotlib.axes.Axes.twiny) for twiny gives the note

> For those who are ‘picking’ artists while using twiny, pick events are
>   only called for the artists in the top-most axes

I realize I need to make these the first axes the top most axes, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was kind of tricky. I thought you would just need to set the active axis as well, using f.sca(a), but that didn't seem to help, i.e., it doesn't matter which axis is active. What you have to do is set the zorder of the two subplots, and give 'a' a higher zorder than 'y'. So, if you add these two lines of code anywhere after you create the two axes objects, I think it should work:

```
a.set_zorder(1)
y.set_zorder(0)
```